# How to include a figure from geogebra?

Tags: discussion, editing, images

I want to post a question regarding geometry. I use the geogebra app for creating a graphic, but I do not know how to bring a drawn figure from there to here. How could I achieve this?

It would be convenient if you know that I am doing all this through a tablet and not a desktop. (I really don't have any idea which tags to add to this question.)

Comment: I believe this is rather a question for geogebra not math.se as the issue is mainly how to export the graphic from  there.

Comment: if you can save an image as a jpeg on your home device, that can be uploaded to a question, there is a landscape icon for starting that process.  If you cannot save it you are probably out of luck.

Comment: I lazily just screenshot it when I'm done.

Comment: What I usually do is first export the graphic view to clipboard. open an image editor, paste the image into editor and then crop and resize. The default from Geogebra itself is usually too large for this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geogebra applets in posts?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12696/geogebra-applets-in-posts)

Comment: Some users voted to close this as a duplicate of [Geogebra applets in posts?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12696/geogebra-applets-in-posts). I do not know much about geogebra, but I think there is difference between this. AFAIK this site does not support embedding geogebra applets, so the other post is feature request. In this post the OP asks how to get an image of something they constructed in geogebra in some format which enables posting it as an here image.

Comment: BTW there are some [questions about geogebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=geogebra+is:q) in the main site. Wouldn't a question asking how to export image from this software an appropriate question for the main site?